# CSS Grid wrapper does not expand to size of items

Tags: css, css-grid

I have an element with `display: grid;`. The parent of the grid has a max-size and will allow the grid to be scrolled if needed.

The issue is that the grid element does not expand to the size of its children. If you scroll right you can see that the color of `.grid` (red) ends and `.b` (blue) keeps going. I'm probably missing a property I don't know about?

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.grid {
  max-width: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 150px;
  background: red;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}

.a {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
  border-bottom: 3px solid green;
}

.b {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="a">a</div>
        <div class="b">b</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try inline-grid instead of grid

Comment: the duplicate deals with block element but the same apply to grid, flexbox, table, etc ... the key is to consider `inline-*`

Comment: In addition to Temani's suggestion `inline-grid` and *probably off-topic* but, (depending on your usecase) I'd suggest using the `repeat()` functionality when declaring your columns, and then possibly introducing variables. https://jsfiddle.net/vje94s2y/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `inline-grid` option in `display` property. 
When you use `inline-grid` then all direct children of the grid container automatically become grid items.

```css
.grid {
  max-width: none;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 150px;
  background: red;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aviboy2006/vLd850os/

Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp